# Poisson equation solver for a large problem

Tags: c++, numerical-analysis

I am looking for a C++ Poisson equation solver library (Laplacian(u(x,y))=f(x,y), Dirichlet boundary conditions) for a large problem. Typically 1000 x 1000 data points, on a regular rectangular grid. Finite difference, multigrid would be fine.

Comment: If I search online I find plenty of them. Are you looking to increase performances?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani: mh, of course I did search, that's why I am asking. You indeed find a number of entries, but many of them are irrelevant (inappropriate or exotic methods), some are overfeatured or may be complex to implement... I am asking for a recommendation by someone who effectively used. I don't want to try five solutions before I end-up on a satisfactory one.

Comment: I see. So I'm not the right person for this.

Comment: code "deal.ll" has c++ solvers and includes poisson solvers as I believe.  I am investigating deal.ll but I am not a competant or experienced user.  Generally has good reputation as I see.

Comment: @tckosvic: thanks for your input. Seems to be on the side of overfeatured, though, and not Windows friendly. (Ok, I didn't mention that.)

Comment: Why would anyone be doing any real numerical computing in windows?  Runs half the speed of linux

Comment: @tckosvic: you seem pretty misinformed. When doing pure computation, the process does not interact with the system at all, so that makes no difference. What matters is a good optimizing compiler.